# How to approach Web App?

Tags: authentication, penetration-test, password-cracking, authorization

I'm doing testing on the app, if we take only login url as a starting point.

How to expand my horizons? 
I want to make my surface wider, really kinda stuck on this one.

Comment: You're essentially asking "How do I test the application?" - which is probably a contender for the broadest question asked here.

Comment: @MechMK1 You are right. Will formulate my question. Thank you.

Comment: Your edit makes the question even broader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [OWASP ASVS](https://owasp.org/www-project-application-security-verification-standard/), the application security verification standard. It is focused on web applications and provides a guideline for the security tests you should perform during a penetration test. Especially chapter V1.2 and chapter V2 cover a broad range of tests that should be done in regard to authentication. Keep in mind that some of them cannot be performed black box.

If you are actually stuck on the login form, I recommend asking your client to provide you with valid user accounts. Doing a penetration test on a login form, which you cannot bypass, will not add much value for your client, so he should be glad to supply you with accounts.